# Árvore estritamente binária

Tags: c, árvore-binária, revisão-de-código

> Uma árvore binária de busca é estritamente binária se todos os nós da árvore tem 2 filhos ou nenhum. Implemente uma função que verifica se uma árvore binária de busca é estritamente binária.

```
// Estrutura de dados
typedef struct {
    int chave;
}tipo_elemento;

typedef struct nodo{
    struct nodo *dir, *esq;
    tipo_elemento e;
}tipo_nodo;

typedef tipo_nodo *apontador;

// Implementação
int estritamente_bin(apontador a){
    if(!a->dir && !a->esq)
        return 1;

    if(a->dir && a->esq)
        return estritamente_bin(a->esq) && estritamente_bin(a->dir);

    return 0;
}
```

Alguma sugestão e/ou crítica para melhorar a implementação acima?

Comment: Seu código está correto. Se as operações de alteração de árvore forem poucas, mas as de consulta de estado forem muitas, é possível inserir alguns metadados nos nós da árvore para conter essa informação e ser mais eficiente. Também não tenho certeza de `code review` é apropriado ao modelo do SOpt, por isso voto pelo fechamento

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O seu código está bom, tenho apenas umas poucas sugestões.

A primeira é quanto a isso:

```
typedef tipo_nodo *apontador;
```

Isso daí acho que não contribui muito para a legibilidade do código. Eu acho que é importante que ponteiros sejam claramente tratados como tal, ainda mais quando se usa o operador `->`, e portanto sugiro usar `tipo_nodo *` na função `estritamente_bin`.

A função `estritamente_bin` pode ser reduzida a isso:

```
int estritamente_bin(tipo_nodo *a) {
    return (!a->dir && !a->esq)
            || (a->dir && a->esq && estritamente_bin(a->esq) && estritamente_bin(a->dir));
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pelas sugestões!